# How to create separate model for each user type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have the basic User model that deals with the users table, I have two types of users, each type has different attributes and reads those attributes form a different database.

```
  User: name, email, type (x,y)
  type_x: gender, age
  type_y: color, location
```

So I have the `user` table, the `type_x` table, and the `type_y` table.

How can I create three different models, User, Typex, and Typey so that I can retrieve the data of each model in a different way and dealing with a different table?

Comment: [Polymorphic relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) might help, where each type can belong to a user (assuming each type table has an associated `user_id`. Not *exactly* what you're asking for, but can fulfill your need I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to create 3 different models.

If classes `TypeX` and `TypeY` do use methods from `User` class, extend that class.
If not needed, just extend `Eloqeunt` class.

You wrote, each type would use different database - you have to specify different connection then.
Well, just add `$connection` property. Laravel uses named connections so use the name of connections specified in `app/config/database.php` file.

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent
{
    // this model loads data user table from default connection
    protected $table = 'user';

    // other methods...
}

class TypeX extends User
{
    // this model loads data user table
    protected $table = 'user';  

    // ... but from different DB connection
    protected $connection = 'connection1';
}

class TypeY extends User
{
    // this model loads data user table
    protected $table = 'user';

    // ... but from different DB connection
    protected $connection = 'connection2';
}
```